# Translation Train

Tags: word, wordplay, language

Complete the following bizarre translations to figure out if I made this puzzle too difficult:

> $\mathbf 6$ $\rightarrow$ *Sus Domesticus* $\rightarrow$ **!** $\rightarrow$ Auf Englisch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Partial answer:

As @El-Guest notes,

> *Sus domesticus* is Latin for pig -> suggests "pig latin" as a translation

Appying this to the first element:

> Bold six -> Oldbay Ixsay

There are many places this could go next:

> Old Bay is a seasoning mix; a Bay could refer to a horse, making an Old Bay a Nag; IX could be read as Nine in roman numerals; the "x" could mean times or by; others...

---

Or, the above is maybe over thinking it.

> Six in pig latin is Ixsay. IX = 9; 9 say (exclaim) in German, then translate to English: Nein! -> No!

So the answer is:

> No! The puzzle is not too difficult :)

Comment: Glad to hear it, and thanks for proving your answer correct! :-)  (Tick will follow a bit later.)

Answer (score 1):

So from what I can tell,

> 6 could be Hex or Sex or Six or pronounced like Cease (in French)...

Then

> *Sus domesticus* is a pig or a hog (Latin taxonomic name)...

And then

> The symbol ! Is used in math to negate things (eg. NOT something)...

And finally

> *Auf Englisch* means In English, in German.

So putting this all together, we get...

> Cease-pig *or speaking* not in English?

I feel I have some of the idea but I hope the parts I didn’t get made you laugh!